# Multi-monitor SLI when not using 3D

Tags: multiple-monitors, sli

I have read that multi-monitor is limited to 2 screens when using SLi, but is that only the case when 3D games are running or do I need to turn SLi on just before starting a game and turn it off afterwards?

Comment: Where did you read that?  What have you tried already?

Comment: I haven't built a SLi system yet, just researching my options. I read this http://superuser.com/questions/434397/can-i-use-4-monitors-with-2-sli-cards but wanted to know about regular desktop mode, not just fullscreen 3D stuff