# Can I drive four monitors from an SLI setup with 2 outputs on each card?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a quad monitor setup with an HD5570 workstation graphics card.

I am wondering before the fact if it is possible to use two high-performance cards such as an R9 or GTX 9X0 series in CrossFire or SLI mode to drive all four monitors.

There is an [older question](https://superuser.com/questions/434397/can-i-use-4-monitors-with-2-sli-cards) that answers this, but it is from 2012, and I'd like to get an updated answer if it has changed and what the ramifications are with ATI's Eyefinity project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer, yes.

Some additional items to note, the *ATI* chipset which will utilize *Eyefinity* may potentially be able to power three or even four, but it will require some additional adapters.  To be exact, they'll require an active adapter.  The products supported can be found their web-site.  So one card may indeed work, but two will obviously be better.

You may actually be able to use one card and your integrated graphics if your board supports it.

With Nvidia you'll more than likely need both cards, they tend to actually share bandwidth between two ports within the card.

If you indeed do both cards, it will work certainly.